# How do I clear the input of a Smart Panel dialog (PXFilter)?

Tags: acumatica

I have created a smart panel in a custom screen to ask for user input that is used to facilitate moving stock from normal inventory into an isolation area.  My original smart panel example that I always use is the Copy Order in the SOOrderEntry graph (SO301000).  In this case, I need to do a bit of validation, and the user may very well decide to close the smart panel and update the document in the screen before reopening the smart panel again.  If the user clicks the cancel button, I need the smart panel to reset back to defaults every time it is opened.

I thought this might be handled in the ASPX screen definition, but I can't find the right setting for the form itself.  I use AutoRefresh on selectors to refresh every time they are opened, but I need the form itself to do the same and refresh back to default every time it is opened.  The desired behavior DOES occur automatically when I navigate to another record of the graph's primary DAC, but I cannot seem to force the smart panel to refresh automatically every time it is opened.  I looked at the various options for the form in ASPX, but I overlooked it if it is there.

Similarly to CopyOrder on SOOrderEntry, here is my code sample from my graph.

```
public PXFilter<StockParamFilter> stockparamfilter;

#region AddFromStock
public PXAction<MyTag> addFromStock;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.AddFromStock, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
[PXButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable AddFromStock(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    MyTag tag = Tags.Current;

    if (tag?.TranRefNbr != null)
    {
        throw new PXException(Messages.TagAlreadyReceived);
    }

    MyTagEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<MyTagEntry>();

    WebDialogResult dialogResult = stockparamfilter.AskExt(setStockStateFilter, true);
    if (dialogResult == WebDialogResult.OK || (IsContractBasedAPI && dialogResult == WebDialogResult.Yes))
    {
        // My Business Logic Here
    }
    return adapter.Get();
}
#endregion

#region CheckStockParams (OK Button in Smart Panel)
public PXAction<MyTag> checkStockParams;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "OK", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXLookupButton]
public virtual IEnumerable CheckStockParams(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    return adapter.Get();
}
#endregion

#region setStockStateFilter
private void setStockStateFilter(PXGraph aGraph, string ViewName)
{
    checkStockStateFilter();
}
#endregion

#region checkStockStateFilter
protected virtual void checkStockStateFilter()
{
    // My Business Logic Here to set bool enableStockParams = ???
    checkStockParams.SetEnabled(enableStockParams);
}
#endregion
```

This seems like something I did in the past, but I cannot seem to locate the code.  I think it is related to stockparamfilter being a PXFilter instead of a PXSelect (or SelectFrom).

I have tried stockparamfilter.ClearDialog() with no luck.  I have tried stockparamfilter.RequestRefresh() with no luck.  I even tried stockparamfilter.DeleteCurrent() which seemed to work when I hit Cancel, but then my code did not execute when I hit OK.  I also seemed to get the desired results when I used stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.locationID>(filter); on every field, until I hit OK which did nothing.  It's like every time I try to manipulate the filter, I break the smart panel without any errors in the trace.  In fact, here is the list of what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
StockParamFilter filter = stockparamfilter.Current;
stockparamfilter.View.Clear();
stockparamfilter.View.RequestRefresh();

stockparamfilter.Cache.Clear();
stockparamfilter.View.RequestRefresh();
stockparamfilter.View.RequestFiltersReset();
stockparamfilter.DeleteCurrent();

stockparamfilter.ClearDialog();

stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.locationID>(filter);
stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.toLocationID>(filter);
stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.qty>(filter);
stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.lotSerialNbr>(filter);
stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.origRefNbr>(filter);
```

What is the ASPX code or C# Code that will let me reset the smart panel to defaults?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A big thanks to Hughes Beausejour at Acumatica for the offline assist.  Posting solution for anyone else that may have this issue.

First, it is important to understand that AskExt generates 2 passes of the code.  The first pass prompts the smart panel.  Upon response to the smart panel, the code executes again, but in this second context skips the ask.  With that in mind, the reason for my code not working became clear, as Hughes explained to me.

To execute the code when the form is initialized, that code must be executed before the ask occurs.  Otherwise, the form is presented and then the initializing code is executed too late.  Additionally, it must be conditioned such that it only fires when the smart panel was not given an OK response by the user.  *(Not realizing the code executes twice, I was unaware that I was resetting the fields on both passes. When I could get the form to reset, the subsequent processing would fail becuase I was resetting it on that pass as well.)*  Following that code, the AskExt can be used to present the form along with the normal processing of the user response.

My code, to show the working example, is as follows:

```
StockParamFilter filter = stockparamfilter.Current;

// If the user response is anything except an affirmative, default the fields
if (!(stockparamfilter.View.Answer == WebDialogResult.OK || (IsContractBasedAPI && stockparamfilter.View.Answer == WebDialogResult.Yes)))
{
    stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.locationID>(filter);
    stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.toLocationID>(filter);
    stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.qty>(filter);
    stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.lotSerialNbr>(filter);
    stockparamfilter.Cache.SetDefaultExt<StockParamFilter.origRefNbr>(filter);
}

// Present the Smart Panel Dialog (happens only on the 1st pass - AskExt causes the code to execute twice)
WebDialogResult dialogResult = stockparamfilter.AskExt(setStockStateFilter, true);

// If the response was affirmative, execute the business logic
if (dialogResult == WebDialogResult.OK || (IsContractBasedAPI && dialogResult == WebDialogResult.Yes))
{
    // Do Business Logic Based On User Response In Smart Panel
}
```